# Laravel /ORM Doesnt create related table

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, relation

How can I add value to a ORM related variable?

It contains a news and comments Model, as shown below:

```
class News extends Model {

protected $connection = 'mysql';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $table = 'news';
protected $fillable = array(
    'id',
    'name',
    'category',
    'type',
    'datetime',
    'shortdesc',
    'desciption'

);
 public $timestamps = false;

 public function comments()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Comments');
}
```

> Comments table

```
class Comments extends Model {

protected $connection = 'mysql';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $table = 'comments';
protected $fillable = array(
    'id',
    'news_id',
    'name',
    'description'
);
 public $timestamps = false;



 public function news()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\News','news_id');
}};
```

> And when I try to add this values it creates only **News** table 
>    without related **Comments** table.(Doesn't throw any exception, just creates **News** table)

```
 public function AddData()
{
 $row=new News;
 $row->name="Myname";
 $row->category="vcc";
 $row->type="2";
 $row->comments()->news_id="1";
 $row->comments()->name="someval";

$row->save();
return view::make('first_view');
}
```

Comment: First, show us how you create a new News item.

Comment: But you created both two tables, right? Can you show the definition?

Comment: can your code run? see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem when you are inserting your related Comment model. There are many ways to solve your problem.

Solution I prefer to use:

```
public function AddData()
{

    // Create news model
    $news = News::create([
        'name' => 'Some name',
        'category' => 'somecategory',
        ....
    ]);

    // Create comment through news model
    // news_id will automatically be inserted
    $comment = $news->comments()->create([
        'name' => 'some name'
    ]);

}
```

[See documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models)